# Htaccess ReWrite except one directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ home.php?id=$1
```

Which rewrites to `domain.com/test to domain.com/home.php?id=test`

How can I keep this code but make certain directories not rewrite to home.php?id=???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/somedir/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ home.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This will skip the rule for a directory `/somedir`

To skip all directories use it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ home.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```